# Mercurial: How to merge with a non-head revision?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Merging in my Mercurial repository is not working like I expected.

Several days ago I started work on a feature then realized I could not finish it before sprint end.  I updated back to the point in time that I started work and continued from there (effectively creating a branch).  Now I am ready to merge the changes from that branch back into the tip, yet for some reason when I merge nothing happens.  TortoiseHg says the merge went fine, and both the tip and the changeset that I'm trying to merge from are bold in the Repository Explorer but none of the changes from the branch are in my working directory.

Here is a video of the unexpected behavior: http://screencast.com/t/ZTQ0ZjU1NTM

Notice that when I go to commit there are no changes detected.  In what way is this a merge?

Am I missing something?  Is Hg broken?  I could've sworn that I've done this before and it went off without a hitch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try it from the command line?

```
hg update -r48
hg merge
hg commit -m "merged"
```

Comment: That did it, thanks.  I guess it was a problem with TortoiseHg.